# How do I append to a struct set in CFPROPERTY?

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I'm using `<cfproperty />` to make use of implicit **getters** and **setters** in ColdFusion (Railo).

However, for more complex values like structs and arrays, how can I append to these?

```
<cfproperty name="settings" type="struct" />
```

How can I append an item into the property called settings? If I do the following:

```
<cfset setSettings(structAppend(getSettings(), { "hello" = "world" })) />
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Am I missing something here? I'm new to the cfproperty tag and thought it would be a time saver, but I can't figure this out.

Also, as a bonus how would I set a default value to these complex data types?

Thanks,
Mikey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things here...

```
<cfset setSettings(structAppend(getSettings(), { "hello" = "world" })) />
```

Settings is a `struct` but `structAppend()` returns a boolean. Do your struct appending before this line. Second, structs are always passed by reference, meaning, if you do `getSettings()` you get a `struct`, which you can make changes to. Another call to `getSettings()` will return the same `struct` with the updated settings.

All you need is this:

```
<cfset structAppend(getSettings(), { "hello" = "world" }) />
```

One last thing. You could be getting a null pointer exception because `getSettings()` starts uninitialized. In your cfc, in the constructor area (after your properties), you should set an initial settings `struct`, like this:

```
<cfset setSettings({}) />
```

Comment: It seems your last point solved the issue. I wasn't aware I had to explicitly set() the type like that. I assume the type attribute would handle that. Thanks!

Comment: Properties are declared but not initialized. If you run the getter before initializing it, it returns a null (and will destroy any variable you try to set it to), but in certain cases it's treated as an empty string (`len(getSomeProperty())==0`). I use a bean factory to initialize `struct` and `array` properties automatically.